# QlikSense Error

Tags: error-log, qliksense

Some of the error that have come out when I download the script log. This came out. I am quite new to qliksense QMC, can somebody help to explain this. Thank you.

The lines are :

2018-01-08 14:04:39      Error: Connector reply error: Unable to get column information for the fields that are used in the query:

2018-01-08 14:04:39          ERROR [HY000] [Qlik][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]Unexpected Network Error.

[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**2018-01-08 14:04:39 Error: Connector reply error: Unable to get column information for the fields that are used in the query:**

This line in the error log is due to the second line below.

**2018-01-08 14:04:39 ERROR [HY000] [Qlik][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]Unexpected Network Error.**
This line in the log specifies that you are unable to connect the data source using Oracle driver.

Check following
1. You are having data source up and running.
2. Check the ODBC drive connection which is trying to connect to your qliksense editor.
3. You are using correct ODBC driver and connection name.